# time_zone_options_for_select to print hours to UTC offsets as value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code to let user select their timezone.

```
<%= time_zone_options_for_select(@corp.timezone, nil, ActiveSupport::TimeZone) %>
```

The problem is that code produce this html

```
<option value="American Samoa">(GMT-11:00) American Samoa</option>
```

I need it to be like the following

```
<option value="-11:00">(GMT-11:00) American Samoa</option>
```

How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason you need to store the offset? I would suggest simplifying like so:

#### keep view the same

```
time_zone_options_for_select(@corp.timezone, nil, ActiveSupport::TimeZone)
```

#### model

```
validates :timezone, inclusion: { in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys }
```

#### convert

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone(@corp.timezone)

DateTime.now.in_time_zone("Hawaii")
# => Thu, 07 Aug 2014 23:19:03 HST -10:00
```

---

However, to answer your question. See documentation for [`time_zone_options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-time_zone_options_for_select) along with the source code.

The last argument takes a model. In this case, `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`. It then uses `model.all` to get a list of timezones, and extracts label, value (respectively) as `[instance.to_s, instance.name]`.

Note, each `TimeZone` instance has `utc_offset`.

```
TimeZone.new("Hawaii").utc_offset
# => -36000
```

This means you could pass `time_zone_options_for_select` your own custom class that implements `self.all` and patches `instance.name`.

---

You could also skip `time_zone_options_for_select` and use `options_for_select`, passing in this custom array:

#### helper

```
def timezone_options
  ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map do |zone|
    [zone.to_s, timezone_to_offset_string(zone)]
  end
end

def timezone_to_offset_string(timezone)
  (timezone.utc_offset / 3600).to_s + ":00"
end
```

#### view

```
options_for_select(timezone_options, @corp.timezone)
```

But then you lose `priority` option from `time_zone_options_for_select`. So, as you can see, it's probably best to just stick to conventions.